# Cannot add a product to My Support Profile: "serial number is associated to another Apple ID"

Tags: icloud, apple-id, serial-number

I am trying to add the iMac I bought in 2011 to "[My Support Profile](https://supportprofile.apple.com/regProd)".

So I copied the serial number from the "About this Mac" window, but when I entered it, I got this message:

[image: According to our records, this serial number is associated to another Apple ID. If you have more than one Apple ID, log in to My Support Profile with that Apple ID to see your other added products. Not sure if you have another Apple ID?]

I never had another Apple ID.

How do I prove Apple this computer is actually really my computer?

This problem is really annoying, and because of the same issue I have only been able to add 2 devices out of 8 that I own...

**EDIT**: *As of October 2016; the URL seems to have moved [here](https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage) for the list of devices paired with your Apple ID. And it seems that the question is also now obsolete since only devices that a user can log into (such as devices with iOS, macOS or tvOS) can be added, so no more iPods.*

[image]

Comment: Why the down voting? Did someone understand something that I didn't and can't be bothered explaining?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a proof of purchase or a receipt, Apple support will likely be help you correct this. Without these, they may question whether or not you own the computer.

Comment: Thanks, I understand suspicion might arise but when does the pairing between ID and SN happen? In your answer I'd love to see a link, claiming that Apple products cannot be given as a gift or bought second-hand, especially in this pre-holiday period, it would be interesting... They clearly don't advertise this "rule" much. I bought 2 devices on craigslist, I got one at a raffle at my work, one was a girlfriend's gift, and I actually bought my iMac at the Apple store, but I can't add any of these on my ID. And what makes no sense, I could add my iPod nano that I bought on craigslist.

Comment: (an ideal answer might include second-hand buying tips for Apple products, what documents to keep when purchasing an Apple product, what to do if someone gives you an Apple product, etc, with links to the Apple website detailing those steps)

Comment: It's not that they cannot be bought second-hand or as a gift, but there is no way to distinguish between a stolen computer and a gifted one in this case, unless the SN has been reported stolen or it has been remotely locked. In any case, the only way to find out is by contacting support. The pairing occurs when you add it to your support profile, as you are trying to do. If you buy one second-hand, you should attempt to obtain the proof-of-purchase.

Comment: Thanks, as I said feel free to make your answer better by linking to official sources so that I can validate it. The way it's set up by Apple puts people who receive a gift, buy second hand products or even buy a brand new product and can't add it on website on the same level as thieves, I think it's a pretty big deal actually! "Guilty until proven innocent" isn't a way to treat loyal customers...